# SQL multiple keyword full text search on relational tables to return all results rated by relevancy

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have one table called “location_level” which associates a unique “id” field to a “value” field (United States, Brazil, Michigan). The “value” field is set to a full text index.

I have another table called “poll_location_level” which associates a “poll_id” field to one of the unique “id” fields from “location_level”.

I am trying to figure out how to do a full text search on several terms at once that will return all “poll_id” fields in “poll_location_level” with a relevancy rating associated with each.

Therefore, if a search includes “Michigan” + “United States” then I would like:

1) “poll_id” 1 (from “poll_location_level”) to be returned with the highest relevancy rating (since “poll_id” 1 is associated with both “location_level_id” 1 and 3)

2) “poll_id” 3 (from “poll_location_level”) to be returned with the second highest rating (since “poll_id” 3 is associated with “location_level_id” 3)

3) “poll_id” 2 (from “poll_location_level”) to be returned with the lowest rating (since “poll_id” 2 is not associated with any “location_level_id” fields.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/968e5/4

Answer (score 0):

A full text search turned out to be the wrong approach because I am looking for exact matches.

Here is what I ended up using to do exactly what I needed to do (thanks to some help from IRC):

SELECT ploc.poll_id, COUNT(loc.id) AS n FROM poll_location_level AS ploc LEFT JOIN location_level AS loc ON ploc.location_level_id = loc.id AND loc.value IN ('United States', 'Michigan') GROUP BY ploc.poll_id ORDER BY n DESC